# Sharepoint 2020, getting approvers' name and approve date displayed in columms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, content-approval

We are new at Sharepoint and workflow application. We have been trying to organize a workflow for getting simple approvals for pdf files. We have tried set an approval, we have to go to Power Automate and Create Workflow. But it seems that none of the available options work. The problem is that when clicking My workflows in Power Automate, none of the actions we do is linked to our initial library. Our objective is just to add 2-3 names (as visitors) to see (not edit) a pdf file, to have them approve and create a list of the approvers and the aproval dates. Any assistance will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Also, there's not a SharePoint 2020 version, are you talking about SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

For the part:

> Our objective is just to add 2-3 names (as visitors) to see (not edit)
> a pdf file, to have them approve and create a list of the approvers
> and the aproval dates.

I assume you want the user who start the approval process to select the approvers and set a due date for them.

You can set the manually start trigger to add a Email filed for end users to fill in the approvers and use them in the approval process.
[image]

Granting users permission in Flow you will need to call HTTP service which is a bit complex for new users so for the visitors, you will better grant them permission before the approval process.